# Why does this navigation link not work as expected?

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui

I tried to implement a login screen in swift 5 but the login navigation link doesn't seem to check the isActive variable from my view model. When I click it the first time it leads me to the next view although the login data is not correct. When I go back then and try to login again it checks the data.

LoginView:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LoginView: View {

@ObservedObject var viewModel: LoginViewModel

var username_text_field: some View {
    TextField("Username", text: $viewModel.username)
}

var password_secure_field: some View {
    SecureField("Password", text: $viewModel.password)
}

var login_button: some View {
    
    NavigationLink(
        destination: MenuView(),
        isActive: $viewModel.is_valid
    ) {
        Text("LOGIN").onTapGesture {
            viewModel.login()
        }
    }
}

var body: some View {
    
    NavigationView {
        
        VStack {
            Group {
                username_text_field
                password_secure_field
                login_button
            } 
        }
    }
}
}
```

Login ViewModel:

```
import SwiftUI

final class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {

@Published var username = ""
@Published var password = ""
@Published var is_valid = false

func login() {
    self.is_valid = false
}
}
```

Is there something wrong with this approach or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 0):

What Xcode version are you using? I'm on Version 12.5 (12E262) with iOS 14.5 and your code works fine. However, you might want to move the `LOGIN` button outside of the `NavigationLink`, so that it's guaranteed to *only trigger* based on `isActive`.

```
var login_button: some View {
    Button {
        viewModel.login()
    } label: {
        Text("LOGIN")
    }
}
```

```
NavigationView {
    
    VStack {
        Group {
            username_text_field
            password_secure_field
            login_button
            
            NavigationLink(
                destination: Text("Menu View"),
                isActive: $viewModel.is_valid
            ) { EmptyView() } /// pass in `EmptyView`
        }
    }
}
```

---

Old answer:

Change `login()` to this:

```
func login() {
    self.is_valid = true /// true, not false!
}
```

Also you should use camel case in Swift, so `self.isValid` instead of `self.is_valid`.

Comment: In the login function I would check the credentials and if they are valid I would set is_valid to true. I only set it to false for testing - that would mean that the data does not match and the login should not work (but it does).